# Sending image data through SyncVar doesn't work (Mirror Networking)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

When `SetTexture` is run on the host it displays the sprite and works correctly, however on the client it displays this error:

> SetPixels32 called with invalid number of pixels in the array
> UnityEngine.Texture2D:SetPixels32 (UnityEngine.Color32[])
> Mirror.NetworkReaderExtensions:ReadTexture2D (Mirror.NetworkReader) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkReaderExtensions.cs:343)
> Player:DeserializeSyncVars (Mirror.NetworkReader,bool)
> Mirror.NetworkBehaviour:OnDeserialize (Mirror.NetworkReader,bool) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkBehaviour.cs:979)
> Mirror.NetworkIdentity:OnDeserializeSafely (Mirror.NetworkBehaviour,Mirror.NetworkReader,bool) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkIdentity.cs:1022)

(*And more but I think the more important thing in the error is the first line*)

This is the code: basically users can choose an image of their computer, which is stored in the `networkManager.clientProfile` variable. The image is sent to the server, and the texture variable changes, so the hook code should change the sprite for all clients.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Mirror;

public class Player : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] 
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    [SyncVar(hook = nameof(SetTexture))] 
    Texture2D textureSprite;

    void SetTexture(Texture2D oldTexture, Texture2D newTexture)
    {
        Sprite newSprite = Sprite.Create(newTexture, new Rect(0, 0, newTexture.width, newTexture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 256);
        spriteRenderer.sprite = newSprite;
    }

    public override void OnStartClient()
    {
        base.OnStartClient();

        // networkManager.clientProfile is a Texture2D stored locally
        CmdSetSprite(networkManager.clientProfile.EncodeToPNG());
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSetSprite(byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(5, 5);
            tex.LoadImage(bytes);

            textureSprite = tex;
        }
    }
}
```